# Unit and Integration Tests . Best practice to keep them in solution

Tags: .net, testing

We have practice to cover some basic functionality with unit tests project (MSTest framework), while complex integration tests (that require external data from xml files, highly customozible run, external connections and option to run outside MS Studio in Test and Production environments) as console applications.

Is it ok or shall we migrate all console code to MSTest/NUnit framework? I guess there is no  problem to use console-integration-tests applications in night time builds or what so ever?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to easily schedule your integration tests as part of your continuous integration process for build quality purposes, it would make sense to use a testing framework. That way, if a code change causes an integration test to start failing, you get immediate feedback without having to monitor your console applications or their output.

Comment: I guess I can integrate our custom console integration-test applications into Continous Integration services (such as Cruise Control) by exit codes. For Cruise Control it's called: Executable Task: http://build.nauck-it.de/doc/CCNET/Executable%20Task.html